# Media Query iPhone

Tags: css, media-queries

I am developing one website for mobiles and tablets. for iPhone 5 i am using

```
@media only screen
and (max-device-width: 320px)
and (orientation: portrait) {}
```

and

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 568px)
and (orientation : landscape) {}
```

and for ipad I am using

```
link rel="" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href=""

link rel="" media="all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait )" href=""
```

but both are merging , don't know how.

Is there any other way to use ?

Comment: What do you mean by "both are merging"?

Comment: Both means I am testing on iPhone5 and iPad. If I remove iPhone media then its will work on ipad and If i remove ipad media then it will work on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Use only '@media screen and (max-width: Xpx)' at the bottom of your css file.

This Chrome app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh will give you all the most common screen sizes for you to auto resize your browser windows.

Just use a number a little larger than the screen width, to have a margin of error, and you are good to go.

I like to use:
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px){}
@media screen and (max-width: 660px){}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){}